# Cómo leer un archivo de texto de una lista o array con Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Quiero leer unos arrays de un archivo, y agregarle cada palabra en el array al input del usuario. Imaginate que el input del usuario es `wwww.google.com/` la aplicación agrega cada palabra en el array atrás del enlace hasta que se termine la lista.

```
google.com/
google.com/test.html
google.com/test1.html
```

yo puedo hacer esto si hago un array en el programa y funciona bien pero cuando quiero leer de un archivo, en vez de leer la palabra entera solo lee letra por letra.

```
google.com/
google.com/t
google.com/e
google.com/s
google.com/t
```

y continua así. Como puedo hacer que cuando lee el archivo lea la palabra entera en vez de letra por letra.
Aquí esta mi código si lo necesitas de referencia un ejemplo del array:

### ['test/','test1/','test2/']

```
website = raw_input(Fore.MAGENTA +"> SITIO PARA SCANEAR: ")
if "http://" not in website:
    website ="http://"+ website

with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    array=[]
    for line in ins:
        print line 

for i in line:
    try:
        adminpanel = urllib2.urlopen(website+i)
        checkurl = adminpanel.code
        if checkurl == 200:
            print Fore.GREEN+ website+i," ""              [+] Encontrado [+]"
            continue
        else:
            print Fore.RED+ website+i," ""              [-]Error[-]"
```

Comment: Cual es el contenido de 'test.txt'?

Comment: ['test/','test1/','test2/'] escribi un ejemplo en la pregunta

Comment: Eso es lo que hay en tu archivo de texto? es solo una linea

Comment: no tiene como 100 lineas pero es parecido el contenido

Comment: Entonces, cada linea es una lista? o en total las 100 lineas son una misma lista? Lista es el equivalente de array en python.

Comment: si son como 100 lineas y todos están una lista ['test1','test2','test3'] y continua hasta o mas ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por tus comentarios entiendo que necesitas iterar sobre la lista que está a modo de texto en tu archivo. Puedes hacer uso de [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    cont = ins.read()  # Esto devuelve el contenido completo, no linea por linea
    arr = eval(cont)
    array=arr
    for elemento in array:
        print elemento
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

`eval` es una fuente de inseguridad y se recomienda no usarlo excepto si tú eres el que controla todo el proceso y sabes que *test.txt* es seguro...

Si no quieres usar `eval` tienes varias opciones:

- Puedes guardar las *urls* de forma más estándar para así poder leer el fichero de forma más 'correcta'.
- Puedes usar la función `ast.literal_eval` dentro del módulo `ast`.
- Puedes usar la siguiente función para *parsear* el texto presente en *test.txt* y convertirlo en una lista.

Función a usar:

```
def parsea_lista(tmp):
    tmp = tmp.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").split(",")
    return tmp
```

Esa función funciona para el ejemplo que has puesto, `['test/','test1/','test2/']` pero puede dar errores si ese ejemplo cambia. Lo que hace la función es eliminar los corchetes y las comillas y el resultado final lo convierte a una lista de *strings* separando todo lo que vaya entre comas.

Si lo quieres integrar en el código que te ha dejado @Gocht puedes hacerlo así:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as ins:
    cont = ins.read()  # Esto devuelve el contenido completo, no linea por linea
    array = parsea_lista(cont)
    for elemento in array:
        print elemento
```

En mi opinión, la mejor opción sería la primera pero te obliga a modificar el código que genera *test.txt*.